# Closing old questions from inactive users as unclear

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, vote-to-close

I'm going through old unanswered questions trying to answer, but some of them needs the feedback from OP which have been inactive on the site for a long time so it is unlikely that they will respond. Commenting and waiting for feedback will be a hard to track and putting an answer is not really an option, should this kind of question be closed? Should I just go with what I think and leave it for voting?

[Linked node groups appear as black in preview and final render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15916/linked-node-groups-appear-as-black-in-preview-and-final-render)

[How to set camera rotation on local Z axis to 0](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15922/how-to-set-camera-rotation-on-local-z-axis-to-0)

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16396/rigid-body-animation-objects-are-being-effected-by-an-invisible-boundary

Comment: Every now and then I browse through some tags as well. If it's older than 6 months, with low views (< 10) and no answers and the user hasn't responded or hasn't visited in about that same time it should be ok to flag or delete these. More incentive if it's some localized issue.

Comment: Look at the source of my edit, for SE links the link will automatically turn into the question title.

Comment: @David thanks didn't know that,  about the OP I though that means Post Owner ?

Comment: @Chebhou **O**rignal **P**oster - [Stack Exchange Glossary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40354/278094)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's okay and recommended to do the occasional cleanup every now (we have to keep our quality at a certain standard after all) and then ensure that we have as little unanswered questions as possible and those that are asked have at least one useful answer. That being said there are some questions buried deep in the *Unanswered* tab that can't be answered due to insufficient or incorrect information, poor quality or some other technical issue on the user's end.

Three things I look for when deciding whether a post is worth keeping open or keeping on the site are:

- Is it localized or do you find it *not* helpful to future viewers?
- Does it have more than a few dozen views?
- Has the user made any effort to communicate with anyone via comments etc
- Is the user registered or have they been active on the site in the past 6 - 9 months?

If you come up with a yes, no, no, no or it matches at least 3 of those do cast a delete or close vote or flag it. Closing as unclear won't necessarily apply to all of these however and might discourage a potential answer. Also, if it has a good number of views, that means it might be a recurring problem and worth taking another look at so use your best judgement.